# Use C# to convert a .XFDL file to .PDF

Tags: c#, pdf

Does anyone know of a way using C# to convert a XFDL file to a PDF file that is viewable in a standard PDF viewer (Adobe Reader and the like)?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I have found to handle this is to return a FileContentResult in MVC with the content type of application/vnd.xfdl.  Unfortunately the XFDL format requires a proprietary viewer in order to work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

One way I've seen generating PDF files done is to, within your C# program, temporarily change the printer to a PDF printer (e.g. [Ghostscript](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/)), then print the document out using the default settings, then change the printer back to what it was before.  This approach assumes you have the ability to print out an XFDL file.